# Putting a django login form on every page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I'd like the login form (AuthenticationForm from django.contrib.auth) to appear on every page in my site if the user is not logged in. When the user logs in, they will be redirected to the same page. If there is an error, the error will be shown on the same page with the form.

I suppose you'd need a context processor to provide the form to every template. But, then you'd also need every view to handle the posted form? Does this mean you need to create some middleware? I'm a bit lost.

Is there an accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I eventually found a way of doing this, although I'm sure there are better ways. I created a new middleware class called LoginFormMiddleware. In the process_request method, handle the form more or less the way the auth login view does:

```
class LoginFormMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):

        # if the top login form has been posted
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'is_top_login_form' in request.POST:

            # validate the form
            form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():

                # log the user in
                from django.contrib.auth import login
                login(request, form.get_user())

                # if this is the logout page, then redirect to /
                # so we don't get logged out just after logging in
                if '/account/logout/' in request.get_full_path():
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request)

        # attach the form to the request so it can be accessed within the templates
        request.login_form = form
```

Now if you have the request context processor installed, you can access the form with:

```
{{ request.login_form }}
```

Note that a hidden field 'is_top_login_form' was added to the form so I could distinguish it from other posted forms on the page. Also, the form action is "." instead of the auth login view.

Comment: Thanks, I was tearing my hair out trying to do a similar thing (but through a context processor).

Comment: Really clean solution - but do you have to check everyother form posted in a view to make sure its not is_top_login_form before trying to validate the form, or am i missing some part? I mean in the view later if you have another form does it have to be if reqeust.POST and not 'is_top_login_form' in request.POST?

Comment: Django forms take a [`prefix`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) argument, that you can use instead of the hidden field. e.g. `form=AuthenticationForm(prefix="login", data=request.POST)`.

Answer (score 26):

Using django.contrib.auth, you can put the form code in the base template like so:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url auth_login %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></p>
    <p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /></p>

    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
</form>
```

All you need to do is modify the next value so instead of:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="" />
```

It will now be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
```

To access the request object, make sure you include

```
'django.core.context_processors.request'
```

in your template context processors.  This way you don't have to write any context processors for logins since you are using the Django built-in views.

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about this question. Thanks for this solution. I wasn't aware of the "next" field. If the form validates, this works perfectly. My problem now is how to handle an error. Basically I want to return to the "next" view, but with the login form in the context.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is probably to put the form in manually in a base template like so:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="{% url login %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <input id="username-field" name="username" type="text" />
        <input id="password-field" name="password" type="password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    {# display something else here... #}
{% endif %}
```

and then just write a view hooked up to a URL named "login" to handle the form as you would normally (using a form object that matches the above form). Have the view redirect to `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` to show it on the same page as the one that submitted.

This approach avoids middleware or the need to make a form available to every single template through the context.

**Update**: There are some problems with this approach; need to think on it a little more. Hopefully it at least gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Your form should include `{% csrf_token %}` if you are using a recent version of trunk and if you are posting to the django.contrib.auth view that usually handles login.

Comment: Anyone know how to display the error messages in a template when using the default `AuthenticationForm`? (I'm not using `form.as_p`. Instead I'm using tags such as `form.username` to have more control on customization.

Comment: `{{ form.errors }}`, `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`, and `{{ form.<field>.errors }}`

Comment: Should be `{% if not user.is_authenticated %}` - doesn't make sense to show the form if you are already authenticated and **not** if you aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer of asciitaxi, i use these Middleware Classes to to login and logout:

```
class LoginFormMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.has_key('base-account') and request.POST['base-account'] == 'Login':
            form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST, prefix="login")
            if form.is_valid():
                from django.contrib.auth import login
                login(request, form.get_user())
            request.method = 'GET'
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm(request, prefix="login")
        request.login_form = form

class LogoutFormMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.has_key('base-account') and request.POST['base-account'] == 'Logout':
            from django.contrib.auth import logout
            logout(request)
            request.method = 'GET'
```

An this in my base template:

```
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p id="login">
            {{ request.login_form.non_field_errors }}
            {% for field in request.login_form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag}}: {{ field }}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" name="base-account" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p id="logout">Logged in as <b>{{ request.user.username }}</b>.
            <input type="submit" name="base-account" value="Logout" />
        </p>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Remarks:

- The request.method = 'GET' lines are needed for sites with other forms. Seems a little but akward, but it works fine.
- Since this is displayed on every page, i don't need the the logout special case any more, because i simply don't need a separate logout page
- I need some distinction of my login/logout form BEFORE checking if its valid (thus calling the AuthenticationForm Class. Otherwise, there will be errors when it comes to pages with more forms. Therfore, i use the value of the Submit Button to pick out the relevant cases

Comment: Does this seem to work with class based views for you? I've been using  asciitaxi's code for development, but now that I'm switching to class based views the middleware seems to be breaking. Rather, the middleware above works fine, but the rest of the request gets destroyed, and a blank httpresponse (no errors, no rendered view) is returned. Basically I have to click 'login', then get a white page, then can manually re-request the URL in question. Detailed question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156899/django-loginformmiddleware-breaks-with-class-based-views]

Comment: Where are you getting the form data from? Is it from a form or model? I do not see it being explained.