# Django - Using context_processor

Tags: django, forms, authentication, django-views, django-templates

I want to put a login form everywhere in my webpage so I added a `context_processor` and I included it in base.html file. The problem now is I cannot see the form.

Here is my context_processors.py:

```
def global_login_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formLogin = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if formLogin.is_valid():
            from django.contrib.auth import login
            login(request, formLogin.get_user())
            ...
    else:
        formLogin = LoginForm()

    return {'formLogin': formLogin}
```

And here are the diferents htmls I tried in base.html trying to invoke the form:

```
<form action="/myapp/login/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{global_login_form}}
</form>

<form action="/myapp/login/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{global_login_form.as_p}}
</form>

<form action="/myapp/login/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{request.formLogin}}
</form>
```

first time I load the page, the `context_process` returns `{'formLogin': formLogin}` (cause `formLogin` is `LoginForm()`) but I cannot see the form while inspecting the html. It is not there... but I can see the `csrf_token` so I think I'm not invoking the context properly.

Just it case (maybe the order is incorrect), here is settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "myapp.context_processors.global_login_form",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you said "everywhere on my page", did you actually mean "everywhere on my site", as in you want the login form appearing everywhere so that the user can log in on every page?

Comment: exactly, sorry for my english

Comment: could you post up the view that handles the Post?
If I am understanding this question correctly, the problem is that the template does not have POST context, and so you cannot prefill the form on failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe OP has incorrectly assumed that the template context variable is going to match the function name of the context processor.

OP's context processor `global_login_form()` injects `formLogin` to the template context. Therefore, in the templates the form should be referenced as, for example, `{{ formLogin.as_p }}`.

Answer (score 4):

you must have the form variable in every views, or you should implement a templatetag instead. example:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('registration/login.html', takes_context=True)
def login(context):
    """
    the login form 
    {% load login %}{% login %}
    """
    request = context.get('request', None)
    if not request:
        return 
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return dict(formLogin=AuthenticationForm())
    return dict(user=request.user)
```

Comment: if you visualize the form in firebug you should see that the {{ form.username }} is empty. it's not a css problem but the "form" object is empty.

Answer (score 4):

*I want to use everywhere on my site* gives a signal that you might need a template context processor.

```
def global_login_form(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '/')
    login_form = AuthenticationForm(initial={'next': next})
    return {'login_form': login_form}
```

Having this and adding this context processor to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS section in settings you can use `{{global_login_form}}` in your templates.

Probably you'll have more or less something like this

```
....
<form action="{% url login_view_name %}" method="POST">
{{global_login_form.as_p}}
</form>
....
```

I used this pattern in one of my projects and it worked pretty fine. Only note here that in case if form is not validated it is better to display form in errors on separated page. Here's an example of the view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        login_form =LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            next = login_form.cleaned_data.get('next', '/')
            login(request, login_form.get_user())
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)

    return render_to_response(
        'users/login/login_page.html', 
        {'form': login_form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        )
```

Comment: But, in case form doesn't validate, I want the message error replacing the login form, not to open a diferent page. Is this posible?  In the other hand, do you need to use the next variable?

Comment: You don't need to use next variable, this is an useful extras. Displaying form on the same page it was posted is possible. I guess it is the best to respond with error using ajax. Do you need an example of this?

Comment: Your context processor looks like: {'formLogin': formLogin} so in templates you can use variable {{ formLogin }}.

Comment: Please also do not modify question totally, it makes most of answers useless and unclear.

Comment: There is another issue: there is no login_page.html cause the login form is in base.html, so the users can see it everywhere. How can I get the value of the first argument of render_to_response within the login view??

Comment: As I see on your question you use solution firm form validation and login in context processors. Is it working for you? If yes there's no need to use view from my example. View iwth login_page.html shows login form on separated page as stated in my answer. I also don't know what do you mean by: 'How can I get the value of the first argument of render_to_response within the login view'.

Comment: No, the login in context processor is not working cause, there, request.METHOD is always GET... request.GET is empty so I cannot see the vars I put there while executing the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'login_text'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'password_text'}))
```

This may be your solution. Css is passed as an attribute of the form field, so you don't need to explicitly declare it into your html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to put in POST something that wasn't really POSTed. If you need to get some information to the templatetag, just use the context.

Comment: I did it and I changed the question, the form is missing now!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used a middleware to process the request, instead of using a context_processor. Also, I deleted my login view and I changed the form action to "." so the login functionality is in the middleware.

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page) to find the solution.