# how to add log-in in main_page django

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Putting a django login form on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page)

how can I add a log-in in my main_page in django? let us say that in my main_page i just want to have a log-in. for example, in my www.example.com, i have a log-in division for any user who visit the site.

here is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', main_page),
    (r'^product/$', product_save),
    (r'^reserve/$', reserve_page),
    (r'^product/select/$', product_select),
    (r'^book/$', book_save),
    (r'^api/', include('bookproj.api.urls')),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'media'),
         'show_indexes': True}),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),)
```

my views.py :

```
def main_page(request):
    product = Product.objects.all()

    template = get_template('main_page.html')
    variables = RequestContext(request, { 'product': product})
    return render_to_response(
        'main_page.html', variables
    )
```

in logging-in i just type to `www.example.com/login` , this line direct us to log-in method :

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

but its direct us to another page to call the `login.html`. how can i do it that in `main_page.html` have already a log-in and I cannot go anymore to `www.example.com/login` to log-in?

does anyone have an idea about my question? can i add another views or modify my main_page view?

thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had this issue before , i think code here does exactly what you need 
http://www.nerdydork.com/django-login-form-on-every-page.html

that explains how to put login on every page( by passing it to the base template )
if you want it only in the main page .. pass it to the main page instead of the base template
it's a tutorial that explain how to build such a tasks . hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could use the login required decorator provided in django [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) before your function definition. The link above will lead you to the documentation example, from which you should be able to sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your login form to `main_page.html` template. You can do it manually or (preferably) using [custom context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).