# django - middleware issue

Tags: django, forms, authentication, middleware

I want to put a login form everywhere on my website, after following a few SO answers I decide to write my own middleware like this:

```
class LoginFormMiddleware(object):
'''
Put a login form in everypage of the website
'''
def process_request(self, request):
    # if the top login form has been posted
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        if 'logout_submit' in request.POST:
            # log the user out
            from django.contrib.auth import logout
            logout(request)
            form = LoginForm()
        elif 'login_submit' in request.POST:
            # validate the form
            form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # log the user in
                from django.contrib.auth import login
                login(request, form.get_user())
        else:
            form = LoginForm(request)
    else:
        form = LoginForm(request)
    # attach the form to the request so it can be accessed 
    # within the templates
    request.login_form = form
```

in my settings.py, I have:

```
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS
...
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES + (
    'base.mymiddleware.LoginFormMiddleware',
)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

The form, in base.html to be accesed from everywhere, looks like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <div class="login_box">
                <form action="/myapp/logout/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="col2"><a>{{ user.username }}</a></div>
                    <div class="col3"><input type="submit" value="Logout" name="logout_submit"/></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        {% else %}
                <form action="." method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="login_box">
                        <div class="error_box">
                            {% if request.login_form.errors %}
                                Incorrect User/Password
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col00"> <h4>{{ request.login_form.username.label_tag }}</h3></div>
                        <div class="col11">{{ request.login_form.username }}</div>
                        <div class="col22"><h4>{{ request.login_form.password.label_tag }}</h3></div>
                        <div class="col33">{{ request.login_form.password }}</div>
                        <div class="col44"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="login_submit"/></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}" />
                    </div>
                </form>
        {% endif %}
```

Login works normally but, after doing it, each time I make a GET request user.is_authenticated seems to return false cause what I see is an empty LoginForm instead of the logout form.

I dont know if the problem is in my middleware (when request.method != 'POST' it returns form = LoginForm(request)) or it is something I am missing in my settings, or maybe using middleware for this was not a great idea...

Comment: Please add your related view too.  I personally did not understand the purpose of using middleware in this situation, Django provides a decent module for logging in and out itself.

Comment: My views dont do much cause all the work is in the middleware, in fact, I am using django login inside it. Login and Logout views just have this line: return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')). The porpuse of using middleware is because I want this form everywhere in my site, not in a HTML apart

Comment: Django's auth middleware already adds `user` object to the `dict` which goes to your template, if you're using template inheritance _(you should)_, you can put the form in your base.html, this way it will be loaded on every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe you have seen any SO answers that advocate putting this sort of logic in the middleware. (If you have, post the link so that I can downvote them.)

This really, really, really isn't the place to do this sort of thing. Write a specific view and set the action parameter of the login form to that view.

However, I suspect your underlying issue is that you're not using RequestContext to render the other views, so the user object is not passed to the template.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page

Comment: @juankysmith That's why we have `@login_required` decorator

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but I cannot see the relationship between the decorator and the fact of showing the form after every view

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation doesn't make much sense. A login form with action attribute is "." is wrong and will lead to conflicts.

You should have a login **view**, not a login **middleware**. The action attribute of the login form should be the reversed url of your login view.

In your login form, you should specify a next hidden input for example:

```
<input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.POST.next|default:request.path }}" />
```

Following that, it can be in your base template or anywhere in the website.

This is also valid for logout.

Comment: so... do I have to pass the form in every view's return??

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? Just paste the HTML of the form. That's what we have on betspire.com, it's simple and sane.

Comment: Yes, what I want to do is a login like betspire's. Does it use a view for login?

Comment: Yes, /account/login/. But the base template allows the user to be conducted to this page from any page.

Comment: how is the return of this view?

Comment: It returns a redirection if credentials are valid, otherwise it shows the form. I'm using a builtin view from pinax.apps.account but they all work the same.

Comment: Ok, instead of using that middleware, now I am using django.contrib.auth.views.login for the action of my form, and redirecting to home page after login. The problem now is that user.is_authenticated always returns false, even when the view that loads home page ends up using RequestContext. return render_to_response('myapp/shop_list.html', 
       {'shops': entry_list,},
       context_instance=RequestContext(request)) I am missing something but I dont know what...