# Django LoginFormMiddleware breaks with CVBs and invalid forms

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to make the login form accessible on every page using a middleware suggested on other SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156899/django-loginformmiddleware-breaks-with-class-based-views).

The problem is that when used with class based views without a POST method (e.g. TemplateView), the page is not displayed after an unsuccessful login attempt (form with errors), because the request method is a POST and the view don't have it implemented. For valid forms there is no problem since I can just redirect ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16157343/6702421)). I want to know if there is a better approach to this problem compared to just setting request.method = 'GET' for invalid forms.

```
from MyProj.forms import MyProjTopLoginForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class LoginFormMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        # if the top login form has been posted
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'top_login_form-username' in request.POST:

            # validate the form
            form = MyProjTopLoginForm(prefix="top_login_form", data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():

                # log the user in
                from django.contrib.auth import login
                login(request, form.get_user())

                # if this is the logout page, then redirect to /
                # so we don't get logged out just after logging in
                if reverse('logout') in request.get_full_path():
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                # Redirect to the same page after successfully handling the login form data.
                return HttpResponseRedirect('')
                # We could also do:
                # request.method = 'GET'
                # instead of a redirect, but if a user refreshes the page, they'll get prompted to re-send post data,
                # which is super annoying.

        else:
            form = MyProjTopLoginForm(request, prefix="top_login_form")

        # attach the form to the request so it can be accessed within the templates
        request.top_login_form = form
```

Comment: What about returning a custom error page from your middleware when the login fails? Sidenote: `CsrfViewMiddleware` is view middleware, and only runs after your middleware. You should use `csrf_protect` or call the middleware to make sure your own middleware is protected against CSRF attacks.

Comment: I would prefer to have the errors shown on the form instead of a custom page, but it is an option. Thanks for you sidenote, I updated the code to use the process_view() instead of the process_request(), and put the LoginFormMiddleware after the CsrfViewMiddleware on the MIDDLEWARE setting.