# Single-page login in Django app

Tags: django, authentication, single-page-application

I'm currently using out-of-the-box `django.contrib.auth` to handle authentication in my Django app. This means that the user starts at a log in page and is redirected to the app on successful login. I would like to make my app single-page, including this login process, where a redirect doesn't happen, but maybe a "hot" template switch-out or some fancy client-side div  magic ([that still remains secure](http://jacobbijani.com/post/47867397902/some-paywalls-are-so-pointless)). My [Google searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=single%20page%20login%20django) turned up pretty short, the [closest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page) dealing with putting a log in form on every page.

Any direction or ideas here would be much appreciated. I would obviously prefer to work within the existing confines of `django.contrib.auth` if possible, but I'm open to all solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely. I think you want to have a single page. If so, put logic in your template that checks to see if the user is authenticated. If not, display a login form that POSTS to the appropriate `django.contrib.auth` view. You can supply an argument to this view to have it redirect back to your page. When you come back, the user will be authenticated, so you won't display the login form.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Django-Easy-Pjax https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-pjax - it works like a charm and is well documented. Everything you like is being made with AJAX requests: links, forms using GET and forms using POST.

Essentially you only need to add a `data-pjax="#id_of_the_container_where_the_result_goes"` attribute in your `a` and `form` tags.
And the great thing about it: It updates the title and location bar of your browser.

One caveat: If you want to upload files in some form, this is not supported by Easy-Pjax, so you might want to use some workaround jQuery library for that.

Comment: I want to use `django-easy-pjax` but can't configure it properly using documentation.Here's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075281/django-easy-pjax-not-working-really) how i am trying to use it.How to configure `easy-pjax` I read the docs but its not very clear to me.Is there any example snippet available? I have added in answer my comment what I have done.