# Django-easy-pjax not working really

Tags: python, django, single-page-application, pjax

I use from [django-easy-pjax](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-pjax). 
I have this base code:

ubase.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "/static/js/jquery.pjax.js" %}"></script>
{% block side%}
        It is {% now "c" %} 

sdfdsfdsf
<a href="/uu/">uu</a>
<a href="/uu1/">uu1</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

{%endblock side%}


{%block main%}

sdfdfsdfdsfdsfdfdsf
{%endblock main%}
```

entry_index.html

```
{% extends "ubase.html"|pjax:request %}
{%block main%}
1
{%endblock main%}
```

entry_index2.html

```
{% extends "ubase.html"|pjax:request %}
{%block main%}
2
{%endblock main%}
```

my views:

```
def entry_index1( request ):
    return render_to_response('entry_index1.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def entry_index( request ):
    return render_to_response('entry_index.html', {}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

and my url

```
url(r'^uu/$', search_views.entry_index),
url(r'^uu1/$', search_views.entry_index1),
```

but when I use click on uu link or uu1 link the time change and pjax not work really like this [example](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).Why it is so?

Comment: Can u please edit here what changes you made to make it working and add the code for `pjax_ubase.html` or any other changes u made to your code to make it working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.request` added to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and pjax templates to answer for PJAX request, in your case `pjax_ubase.html`. Take a look at the source code of the template tag: https://github.com/nigma/django-easy-pjax/blob/master/easy_pjax/templatetags/pjax_tags.py

Comment: I am doing exactly similar as described in the question.I have added `django.core.context_processors.request`.What should I write in `pjax_base.html` ? Its still not working.I am new to pjax and i am confused with the `jquery-pjax` i.e. **django-easy-pjax app is a helper that makes it trivial to integrate jquery-pjax with your Django 1.5** . So while using `easy-pjax` should I also have to configure server side stuff? I am trying it from hours , please help me :( Please comment if my doubt doubt is not clear

Comment: @AshishGupta so sorry for the late reply. I have forgotten everything I know about django-easy-pjax, lol. The reason is because there are tons of SPA engine out there way superior to this hack while

Comment: Its okay :)  and its better to forget this and choose a better option :P Even I left it and choose django-rest and angularjs :)

Answer (score 1):

Im sure you don't need this anymore. but you should have added this :D. This is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    console.log("Hello im here ");
    "use strict";
    $(document).pjax("a", "#pjax-container", {timeout: 10000});

    $(document).on("pjax:beforeSend", function(e) {
    console.log("im before sending ");
             return true;

    });

    $(document).on("pjax:send", function(e) {
        $("#loading").removeClass("hidden")
    });

    $(document).on("pjax:complete", function() {
        $("#loading").addClass("hidden")
    });

});
</script>
```