# How to add one form to multiple views?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

For example I have a site, which have multiple pages with corresponding templates, views, urls. And I want to add a form to all (or many) of them, but I dont want to modify code of views. 
How to achieve that?

Comment: This should give you ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page

Comment: I love middlewares!!!

Comment: use template inheritance, app-plugin or inclusion tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom tag that embeds your form, or part of it. It's ok explained in the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) and better in [this blog](http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/post/custom-template-tags-in-django/).

Steps are:

1. create a module (folder + file) with your desired template tags in a
   .py file and their html templates.
2. List item in the .py file register each template tag (link a tag name with a html template)
3. create the template html file
4. List item load this template tag in each html file you want

Comment: Dont forget about that form must not be rendered, but also data passed to it must be processed by view.