# Django validating a (newsletter) form included as part of the base template

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a simple newsletter sign form which I want to include on every page of the site.

Here is the form (subscribers/forms.py)

```
from django import forms

class SubscriberForm(forms.Form):

  email = forms.EmailField()
  first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
  last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I have set up a context processor, so I can render the form in the base template eg

```
def subscriber_form(request):
  return {
    'subscriber_form':SubscriberForm(),
  }
```

And in the base template I have

```
{% include "subscribers/index.html" with form=subscriber_form %}
```

All good.

However, the question is how do I validate the form without taking the user to a different url (and view). I obviously don't want to take the user to (eg) /subscriber/index (hence the action would be "'subscriber/index") and the associated view where I validate the form, because I want the validation errors (if any) to be shown on the (base) template. I would also want the success message to be shown on the base template, rather than taking the user off to a "success" url. It's also not a problem to do the validation using JavaScript but I want to have a fallback in case JS is disabled.

This is all because I want the form to be displayed on every single page - and hence why I need to include it within the base template.

Comment: I'd rather use a custom template tag, inside the function you can access the request object with `take_context=True`

Comment: Sorry - could you expand a bit. Not a huge fan of using template tags unless absolutely necessary, which could well be the case here!

Answer (score 1):

With the assistance of [Putting a django login form on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734055/putting-a-django-login-form-on-every-page?rq=1), I solved it by writing a middleware class:

```
from subscribers.forms import SubscriberForm

class SubscriberFormMiddleware(object):

  def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request):
    return self.get_response(request)

  def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      form = SubscriberForm(request.POST, prefix='subscriber')
        if form.is_valid():
          // do your thing
        request.method = 'GET'
    else:
        form = SubscriberForm(prefix='subscriber')
    request.subscriber_form = form
```

And then in the base template

```
{% include "subscribers/index.html" with form=request.subscriber_form %}
```

The action in the form is set to "." so I can use it on any page.